# Почему после синтеза регистрового файла получается две RAM?

Tags: vhdl

Пишу регистровый файл на VHDL. Вот код:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

library work;
use work.MPFSM.ALL;

entity REGFILE is
    Port (
        CLK      : in STD_LOGIC;
        RST      : in STD_LOGIC;
        W_EN     : in STD_LOGIC;
        R_EN     : in STD_LOGIC;
        ADR_WR   : in NIBBLE;
        ADR_RD_1 : in NIBBLE;
        ADR_RD_2 : in NIBBLE;   

        DIN    : in BYTE;       
        DOUT_1   : out BYTE;
        DOUT_2   : out BYTE
    );
end REGFILE;

architecture Behavioral of REGFILE is

type t_regs is array (0 to 15) of BYTE;
signal c_regs : t_regs := (
    0  => "0000" & "1000", -- P = 8
    1  => "0000" & "0100", -- N = 4
    2  => (others => '0'), -- SL
    3  => (others => '0'), -- SH
    4  => (others => '0'), -- AX
    5  => (others => '0'), -- BX
    6  => (others => '0'), -- CX
    7  => (others => '0'), -- 
    8  => "0000" & "0010", -- A[0] = 0x02 = 2
    9  => "0000" & "1010", -- A[1] = 0x0A = 10
    10 => "0000" & "0001", -- A[2] = 0x01 = 1
    11 => "1111" & "1111", -- A[3] = 0xFF = 255

    others => NONE & NONE
);

signal reg_in    : BYTE;
signal reg_out_1 : BYTE;
signal reg_out_2 : BYTE;
signal adr_for_rd_1 : integer range 0 to 15;
signal adr_for_rd_2 : integer range 0 to 15;
signal adr_for_wr   : integer range 0 to 15;

begin
    reg_in <= DIN;

    adr_for_rd_1 <= CONV_INTEGER(ADR_RD_1);
    adr_for_rd_2 <= CONV_INTEGER(ADR_RD_2);
    adr_for_wr   <= CONV_INTEGER(ADR_WR);

    P_REG_IN: process(CLK, W_EN, adr_for_wr, reg_in)
    begin
        if (W_EN = '1') then
            if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
                c_regs(adr_for_wr) <= reg_in;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    P_REGS_OUT: process(CLK, RST, R_EN, c_regs, adr_for_rd_1, adr_for_rd_2)
    begin
        if (RST = '1') then
            reg_out_1 <= (others => '0');
            reg_out_2 <= (others => '0');
        elsif (R_EN = '1') then
            if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
                reg_out_1 <= c_regs(adr_for_rd_1);
                reg_out_2 <= c_regs(adr_for_rd_2);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;    

    DOUT_1 <= reg_out_1;
    DOUT_2 <= reg_out_2;    
end Behavioral;
```

Проблема в том, что если это дело синтезировать, то на выходе будет 2 RAM. Почему так? Ну никак не могу понять.

**P.S.** `NIBBLE` - это `std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)`, а `BYTE` - `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я этим кодом пытался сделать регистровый файл с двумя портами `READ`, и одним портом `WRITE`. **(RAM 2 read - 1 write)**

Оказывается, в ПО, которое я использовал (Xilinx ISE), были заложены шаблоны для RAM-памяти, и среди них не было памяти *2 Read Port, 1 Write Port* (см. рисунок). Поэтому на синтезе мне выдавало два примитива RAM, которые работали как один RAM.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблему я решил, сделав регистровый файл c `1 read/write` портом и `1 read` портом.